# Using str_split and removing duplicate values from the same record in R

Tags: r, stringr

I have a data frame of book genres.  It began as two columns, one for the title and one for a character string containing multiple genres, similar to this:

```
titles <- c("Harry Potter 1", "To Kill A Mockingbird", "The Hunger Games 1")
genres <- c("Fantasy, Young Adult, Fantasy, Magic", "Classics, Fiction, Historical, Historical Fiction, Academic", "Young Adult, Fiction, Science Fiction, Dystopia, Science Fiction")
books <- tibble(
  title = titles,
  genre = genres)
books

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  title                 genre                                                           
  <chr>                 <chr>                                                           
1 Harry Potter 1        Fantasy, Young Adult, Fantasy, Magic                            
2 To Kill A Mockingbird Classics, Fiction, Historical, Historical Fiction, Academic     
3 The Hunger Games 1    Young Adult, Fiction, Science Fiction, Dystopia, Science Fiction
```

Currently, the genres are in order of how many people categorized them as that genre.  I'd like to split the string of genres into multiple columns indicating a primary genre, a secondary genre, etc., but remove duplicates.  Splitting the genres into multiple columns is easy enough, and I'm sure there is some way to get a function like unique() to work row-wise and omit duplicates, but I'm stuck.  The desired output would be like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  title                                genre1      genre2      genre3          genre4             genre5  
  <chr>                                <chr>       <chr>       <chr>           <chr>              <chr>   
1 Harry Potter and the Sorcerors Stone Fantasy     Young Adult Magic           NA                 NA      
2 To Kill A Mockingbird                Classics    Fiction     Historical      Historical Fiction Academic
3 The Hunger Games                     Young Adult Fiction     Science Fiction Dystopia           NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `stringr::str_split` to make a list-column of genres. `genre` will become a list of character vectors, which you can then unnest, then take distinct observations.

```r
library(tidyverse)

books %>%
  mutate(genre = str_split(genre, ", ")) %>%
  unnest(genre) %>%
  distinct()
#> # A tibble: 12 x 2
#>    title                 genre             
#>    <chr>                 <chr>             
#>  1 Harry Potter 1        Fantasy           
#>  2 Harry Potter 1        Young Adult       
#>  3 Harry Potter 1        Magic             
#>  4 To Kill A Mockingbird Classics          
#>  5 To Kill A Mockingbird Fiction           
#>  6 To Kill A Mockingbird Historical        
#>  7 To Kill A Mockingbird Historical Fiction
#>  8 To Kill A Mockingbird Academic          
#>  9 The Hunger Games 1    Young Adult       
#> 10 The Hunger Games 1    Fiction           
#> 11 The Hunger Games 1    Science Fiction   
#> 12 The Hunger Games 1    Dystopia
```

A shortcut here that I always forget about is `separate_rows`, which does the splitting and unnesting in one step:

```r
books %>%
  separate_rows(genre, sep = ", ") %>%
  distinct()
```

is equivalent to the previous block.

To get this to a wide format, you can use `tidyr::spread`. To make column names `"genre1"`, `"genre2"`, etc. dynamically, I grouped by title and then numbered the unique genres for each title. That way, you don't need to know how many genre columns you need, like you would if you used `tidyr::separate` to split the column instead.

```r
books %>%
  mutate(genre = str_split(genre, ", ")) %>%
  unnest(genre) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(title) %>%
  mutate(num = row_number() %>% paste0("genre", .)) %>%
  spread(key = num, value = genre)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#> # Groups:   title [3]
#>   title                 genre1      genre2      genre3    genre4    genre5
#>   <chr>                 <chr>       <chr>       <chr>     <chr>     <chr> 
#> 1 Harry Potter 1        Fantasy     Young Adult Magic     <NA>      <NA>  
#> 2 The Hunger Games 1    Young Adult Fiction     Science … Dystopia  <NA>  
#> 3 To Kill A Mockingbird Classics    Fiction     Historic… Historic… Acade…
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `separate` with a step to remove non-unique genres before using `separate`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

#remove non-unique genres
books %<>% mutate(genre = map(str_split(genre, ', '), ~ paste(unique(.x), collapse = ','))) 

#separate into columns
books %>% 
  separate(col = 2, into = paste0('genre', seq(max(str_count(books$genre, ',')) + 1L))
           , sep = ',')


# # A tibble: 3 x 6
#   title                 genre1      genre2      genre3          genre4             genre5  
#   <chr>                 <chr>       <chr>       <chr>           <chr>              <chr>   
# 1 Harry Potter 1        Fantasy     Young Adult Magic           NA                 NA      
# 2 To Kill A Mockingbird Classics    Fiction     Historical      Historical Fiction Academic
# 3 The Hunger Games 1    Young Adult Fiction     Science Fiction Dystopia           NA
```

Comment: The only problem with using `separate` is that you hard-code the maximum number of genres as 5, whereas you actually might need to scale either higher or lower

Comment: @camille Good point. I edited my answer so the number of columns isn't hard-coded.

Comment: slight performance gain with `max(str_count(books$genre, ','))+1` instead of `max(str_count(books$genre, ',') + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution using `data.table` and base R.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(books)

books = unique(books[, strsplit(genre, ", "), by = title])
books[, genre:= paste0("genre_", seq_along(V1)), by = title]
dcast(books, title ~ genre, value.var = "V1")
#                    title     genre_1     genre_2         genre_3            genre_4  genre_5
# 1:        Harry Potter 1     Fantasy Young Adult           Magic               <NA>     <NA>
# 2:    The Hunger Games 1 Young Adult     Fiction Science Fiction           Dystopia     <NA>
# 3: To Kill A Mockingbird    Classics     Fiction      Historical Historical Fiction Academic
```

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for adding the missing line! I forgot to copy the part of setting up the data structure into SO example.

Answer (score 1):

We can paste the columns together and use `data.table::fread` magic, then rename our fields.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread(paste(books$title, books$genre, sep=", ",collapse="\n"),header = FALSE,fill=TRUE,sep=",")
setNames(as.data.frame(dt),c("title",paste0("genre",seq(ncol(dt)-1))))
#                   title      genre1      genre2          genre3             genre4          genre5
# 1        Harry Potter 1     Fantasy Young Adult         Fantasy              Magic                
# 2 To Kill A Mockingbird    Classics     Fiction      Historical Historical Fiction        Academic
# 3    The Hunger Games 1 Young Adult     Fiction Science Fiction           Dystopia Science Fiction
```

Answer (score 0):

Its always better to work on data in long-format. Hence, one option is to change data in long format using `tidyr::gather` and then remove duplicate before converting data back to `wide-format`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(splitstackshape)

books %>% cSplit("genre") %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  gather(key, value, - title) %>% distinct(title, value) %>%
  group_by(title) %>%
  mutate(key = paste0("genre",row_number())) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>% as.data.frame()

#                   title      genre1      genre2          genre3             genre4   genre5
# 1        Harry Potter 1     Fantasy Young Adult           Magic               <NA>     <NA>
# 2    The Hunger Games 1 Young Adult     Fiction Science Fiction           Dystopia     <NA>
# 3 To Kill A Mockingbird    Classics     Fiction      Historical Historical Fiction Academic
```